# How do I check a default radio button in react after generation radio buttons with

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, radio-button

I am creating radio buttons with **map** and I want to set one of the buttons to be checked at default. I used "defaultChecked" but it doesn't check the radio button. What is wrong with it ?

```
export const sampleRates = [22000, 32000, 44100, 48000, 88200, 96000, 192000];

  <p>sample rate</p>
    {sampleRates.map((item:any) => (
      <React.Fragment>
        <label htmlFor={item}> {item}</label>
        <input
          name="sampleRate"
          key={item}
          id={item}
          value={item}
          type="radio"
          defaultChecked ={item === (global as any).settings.sample}
          onChange={handleChange}
        />
      </React.Fragment>
    ))}
```

I know that for one radio button such as below if checked={true} then the button gets checked.

```
<p> test </p>
<input type="radio" name="aradio" value="A" checked={true} /> <br />
```

This means that

```
{item === (global as any).settings.sample} is not returning {true}
```

for

```
defaultChecked ={item === (global as any).settings.sample}
```

or

```
checked ={item === (global as any).settings.sample}
```

Do you have any idea ?

Comment: Did you try `checked` as opposed to `defaultChecked`?

Comment: Yes and it didn't "checked".

Comment: You're key is on the wrong spot. It should be on the Fragment. Not sure if that is the source of the issue, but it definitely could be

Comment: Tried   <React.Fragment key={item}> but no luck.